# Viewport in webview does not work

Tags: android, webview, viewport

I use the below html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"/>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 250px; height: 50px; background: green;">250px</div>
<div style="width: 500px; height: 50px; background: yellow;">500px</div>
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 50px; background: red;">1000px</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I set UseWideViewPort to true

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

From what I understand, the div with the 1000px should occupy the entire width, the one with 500px should scale to half the width and the one with 250px should occupy one-fourth the width.

But what really happens is the one with 500px and 1000px goes beyond the screen size. I have attached the screenshot for clarity. I also tried changing `user-scalable=no` with no effect.[image: Screenshot]

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that since you have the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes"/>
```

and you specify the width in your divs, then an actual value of, say, 1000 pixels is being applied to the div. According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUseWideViewPort%28boolean%29):

**When the value is true and the page contains the viewport meta tag, the value of the width specified in the tag is used.**

If you want to achieve divs with widths in respect to one another, an easier ruote would be using percentages, something like:

```
<body>
   <div style="width: 25%; height: 50px; background: green;">25%</div>
   <div style="width: 50%; height: 50px; background: yellow;">50%</div>
   <div style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background: red;">100%</div>
</body>
```

If you aim to have a 'wide' viewport, like a desktop, you should pass true and not specify a  meta tag as mentioned:

**If the page does not contain the tag or does not provide a width, then a wide viewport will be used.**